# DownloadManager download slow on Android 6

Tags: android, cordova, android-6.0-marshmallow

I would like to know why my app's download is incredibly slow when run on Android 6. On Android 4 KitKat, it works fine.

I am using [cordova background download plugin](https://github.com/sgrebnov/cordova-plugin-background-download), and all it does is using `DownloadManager` to instantiate a new `DownloadManager.Request` and start a download.

Is there a known change in Android 6 that might be causing this slow download? Or any suggestions on where else I should look?